# Loss function representing the euclidean distance from prediction to nearest groundtruth in images?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, theano, loss

Is there a loss function that calculates the euclidean distance between a prediction pixel and the nearest groundtruth pixel? Specifically, this is the location distance, not the intensity distance.

This would be on binary predictions and binary groundtruth.

Answer (score 0):

That's the root of mean square error (RMSE), for example:

```
model.compile(loss='rmse', optimizer='adagrad')
```

But it might be better to use mean squared error instead because of what is discussed here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1170:

> i.e. Keras computes the loss batch by batch. To avoid inconsistencies
>   I recommend using MSE instead.

As in:

```
model.compile(loss='rmse', optimizer='adagrad')
```

**But since your data has only binary predictions I would advise the binary_crossentropy instead (https://keras.io/losses/#binary_crossentropy):**

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adagrad')
```

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify -- I meant to say the location distance, not the intensity distance. ie. if I have a prediciton pixel at (1,1) and a groundtruth pixel at (2,3), then the loss would be 2.24.

Comment: Check that example with the root of mean squared error objective.